# how to escape string for UIWebView?

Tags: json, ios, uiwebview, nsstring, escaping

I pull json data from a server. It contains a dictionary with text that I insert into a html template.

**How do I properly escape this string?**

```
NSString* json = /* can be anything, but also garbage */
NSString* json_escaped = [json someEscapeMethod]; ///////  HOW TO ESCAPE THIS ?
NSString* script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"process('%@')", json_escaped];
NSString* result = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
```

---

I currently do like this, but I'm not sure wether the escaping is sufficiently

```
NSString* json_escaped = [json stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\\'"];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I now encode it this way, but the overhead is huge.

```
NSString* json = /* can be anything, but also garbage */
NSString* json_escaped = [json stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString* script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"process('%@')", json_escaped];
NSString* result = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
```

And decode it in javascript like this

```
function process(json_escaped) {
  var json = decodeURIComponent(json_escaped);
  alert('json: ' + json.toString());
}
```

I'm still looking for a better solution with less overhead.

## Update

I have recently learned that there exists several [frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473582/ios-javascript-bridge) for bridging objective-c with javascript.

Comment: This is almost right. if your original string contains single apostrophe this code will not work well. All you have to do in order to fix it is change process('%@') to process("%@"). single apostrophe (') is not getting encoded by stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding where double apostrophe (") is.

Answer (score 0):

The "Escaping Characters in a String" section of [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) may work.