# iOS JavaScript bridge

Tags: javascript, ios, html, uiwebview

I'm working on an app where I'm going to use both HTML5 in UIWebView and native iOS framework together. I know that I can implement communication between JavaScript and Objective-C. Are there any libraries that simplify implementing this communication? I know that there are several libraries to create native iOS apps in HTML5 and javascript (for example AppMobi, PhoneGap), but I'm not sure if there is a library to help create native iOS apps with heavy JavaScript usage. I need to:

1. Execute JS methods from Objective-C
2. Execute Objective-C methods from JS
3. Listen to native JS events from Objective-C (for example DOM ready event)

Comment: You can use WKWebView: call from javascript window.webkit.messageHandlers.{NAME}.postMessage(message) and then handle it with [WKUserContentController addScriptMessageHandler:name:] to call Objective-C from JS

Answer (score 153, accepted):

There are a few libraries, but I didn't used any of these in big projects, so you might want to try them out:

- WebViewJavascriptBridge: https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge
- GAJavaScript: https://github.com/newyankeecodeshop/GAJavaScript

—

However, I think it's something simple enough that you might give it a try yourself. I personally did exactly this when I needed to do that. You might also create a simple library that suits your needs.

#### 1. Execute JS methods from Objective-C

This is really just one line of code.

```
NSString *returnvalue = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"your javascript code string here"];
```

More details on the official [UIWebView Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

#### 2. Execute Objective-C methods from JS

This is unfortunately slightly more complex, because there isn't the same windowScriptObject property (and class) that exists on Mac OSX allowing complete communication between the two.

However, you can easily call from javascript custom-made URLs, like:

```
window.location = yourscheme://callfunction/parameter1/parameter2?parameter3=value
```

And intercept it from Objective-C with this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
   NSURL *URL = [request URL]; 
   if ([[URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"yourscheme"]) {
       // parse the rest of the URL object and execute functions
   } 
}
```

This is not as clean as it should be (or by using windowScriptObject) but it works.

#### 3. Listen to native JS events from Objective-C (for example DOM ready event)

From the above explanation, you see that if you want to do that, you have to create some JavaScript code, attach it to the event you want to monitor and call the correct `window.location` call to be then intercepted.

Again, not clean as it should be, but it works.

Comment: Hint: don't put underscores or similar in your scheme.

Comment: and return a value when you are supposed to :)

Comment: Another Hint: Load the URL in an iFrame to prevent flickering

Comment: @Folleto Hi, you said "but I didn't used any of these in big projects", why not?? did you find a several issue on these libraries??? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No issues. I simply didn't use them, so I can't comment on using them on larger projects. I wanted to clarify that. :)

Comment: https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge : This demo is not working can you please help me?

Answer (score 57):

The suggested method of calling objective c from JS in the accepted answer isn't recommended. One example of problems: if you make two immediate consecutive calls one is ignored (you can't change location too quickly).

I recommend the following alternative approach:

```
function execute(url) 
{
  var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
  iframe.setAttribute("src", url);
  document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
  iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
  iframe = null;
}
```

You call the `execute` function repeatedly and since each call executes in its own iframe, they should not be ignored when called quickly.

Credits to [this guy](http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/).

Comment: You can also use a queue in JavaScript that iOS can fetch to avoid losing messages from .src changing too quickly. The implementation linked above, https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge, uses a queue approach.

Answer (score 12):

**Update:** This has changed in iOS 8. My answer applies to previous versions.

An alternative, that may get you rejected from the app store, is to use WebScriptObject.

These APIs are public on OSX but are not on iOS.

You need to define interfaces to the internal classes.

```
@interface WebScriptObject: NSObject
@end

@interface WebView
- (WebScriptObject *)windowScriptObject;
@end

@interface UIWebDocumentView: UIView
- (WebView *)webView;
@end
```

You need to define your object that's going to serve as your WebScriptObject

```
@interface WebScriptBridge: NSObject
- (void)someEvent: (uint64_t)foo :(NSString *)bar;
- (void)testfoo;
+ (BOOL)isKeyExcludedFromWebScript:(const char *)name;
+ (BOOL)isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript:(SEL)aSelector;
+ (WebScriptBridge*)getWebScriptBridge;
@end

static WebScriptBridge *gWebScriptBridge = nil;

@implementation WebScriptBridge
- (void)someEvent: (uint64_t)foo :(NSString *)bar
{
    NSLog(bar);
}

-(void)testfoo {
    NSLog(@"testfoo!");
}

+ (BOOL)isKeyExcludedFromWebScript:(const char *)name;
{
    return NO;
}

+ (BOOL)isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript:(SEL)aSelector;
{
    return NO;
}

+ (NSString *)webScriptNameForSelector:(SEL)sel
{
    // Naming rules can be found at: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebScripting_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html
    if (sel == @selector(testfoo)) return @"testfoo";
    if (sel == @selector(someEvent::)) return @"someEvent";

    return nil;
}
+ (WebScriptBridge*)getWebScriptBridge {
    if (gWebScriptBridge == nil)
        gWebScriptBridge = [WebScriptBridge new];

    return gWebScriptBridge;
}
@end
```

Now set that an instance to your UIWebView

```
if ([uiWebView.subviews count] > 0) {
    UIView *scrollView = uiWebView.subviews[0];

    for (UIView *childView in scrollView.subviews) {
        if ([childView isKindOfClass:[UIWebDocumentView class]]) {
            UIWebDocumentView *documentView = (UIWebDocumentView *)childView;
            WebScriptObject *wso = documentView.webView.windowScriptObject;

            [wso setValue:[WebScriptBridge getWebScriptBridge] forKey:@"yourBridge"];
        }
    }
}
```

Now inside of your javascript you can call:

```
yourBridge.someEvent(100, "hello");
yourBridge.testfoo();
```

Comment: My app is rejected in app store. 
The issue I received was "The app contains or inherits from non-public classes in AppName: UIWebDocumentView "

Answer (score 6):

[In iOS8 you can look at WKWebView instead of UIWebView](http://nshipster.com/wkwebkit/). This has the following class:
WKScriptMessageHandler: Provides a method for receiving messages from JavaScript running in a webpage.

Comment: Ofcourse, but the method is not executing continuoulsy.. it's a bug in the framework which is provided by apple

Comment: `WKWebView` has a lot of problems, including not handling cookies properly. Just a warning for anyone who comes here thinking it will solve all your problems - google around a bit before adopting it.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible with iOS7, checkout http://blog.bignerdranch.com/3784-javascriptcore-and-ios-7/

Comment: Not really: JavaScriptCore doesn't interact with UIWebViews. It's a great tool, but for a different class of problems. ;)

Comment: Yes it does: JSContext* context = [_webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"]; But JavaScriptCore is too buggy at the moment to be of any real use.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is Appcelerators Titanium offering.   They already have built a Obj-C javascript bridge using the <s>V8 engine</s> JavascriptCore engine used by webkit.   It's also open source, so you'll be able to download it and tinker with the Obj-C as you like.

Comment: @hova, the is no Obj-C V8 bridge. V8 is only leveraged for Android.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the KirinJS project: [Kirin JS](https://github.com/KirinJS/Kirin) which allows to use Javascript for the application logic and native UI adequate to the platform it runs on.

Comment: does anybody still contribute to kirin? i don't see any activity the last few month...

Answer (score 0):

I created a library like WebViewJavascriptBridge, but it's more JQuery-like, has easier to setup and is easier to use. Doesn't rely on jQuery (though to its credit, had I known WebViewJavascriptBridge existed before writing this I may just have held back slightly before diving in). Let me know what you think! [jockeyjs](https://github.com/tcoulter/jockeyjs)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WKWebView on iOS 8, take a look the [XWebView](https://github.com/XWebView/XWebView) which can automatically expose the native interface to javascript.