# Platform-Independent JS->Native Bridge?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile-website

I'm currently working on an app that aggressively uses webviews on both iOS and Android to render content, with native chrome surrounding it. I want to be able to control this chrome via javascript methods.

Android Webview has [addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) which allows this to happen, but iOS does not have this facility. I've already checked out the SO answer at [iOS JavaScript bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473582/ios-javascript-bridge), and this has usefuleinformation, but It's iOS-only; optimally the same underlying web code could power the callbacks on both Andorid and iOS devices.

I'm wondering if something like PhoneGap or Appcelerator provides a way to do this simply; however I don't need their core product (providing a native experience via underlying html/css/js) and I dont even know if what I need is included in their package.

Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the best way would be to do it yourself, combining those two examples:

```
function nativeDoStuff() {
  if (androidbridge != null {
    androidbridge.doStuff();
  }
  else {
    //construct url
    window.location = "myiphonescheme://dostuff";
  }
```

come to think of it, if you're feeling ambitious you could code up a quick javascript object to do it for you:

```
function NativeAppBridge () {
  function runMethod(methodName, params) {
    if (androidbridge != null {
      // If the android bridge and the method you're trying to call exists,
      // we'll just call the method directly:
      if (androidbridge[methodName] != null) {
        androidbridge[methodName].apply(this, params);
      }
    }
    else {
      // building the url is more complicated; best I can think
      // of is something like this:
      var url = "myiphonescheme://" + methodName;
      if (params.length > 0) {
        url += "?"
        var i = 0;
        for (param in params) {
          url += "param" + i + "=" + param;
          ++i;
          if (i < params.length) {
            url += "&";
          } 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using it would then be as simple as:

```
var bridge = new NativeAppBridge();

function onClick() {
  bridge.runMethod("doStuff", null);
}
```

Be aware that I coded this off the top of my head and don't have time to test, at the moment - but I think it should work well enough, provided I didn't make any major mistakes

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [XWebView](https://github.com/XWebView/XWebView) project if you plan to use WKWebView

Answer (score 0):

You can use phonegap plugins to do it. They provide an excelent way to communicate between their webview and your native layer.

[Here you can see how to create one!](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/extending-phonegap-with-native-plugins-for-ios.html)

And my personal opinion on the subject: I've been using phonegap for a while and if you are on webviews, I strongly suggest you to rethink the way you're doing stuff and move to a mobile web platform. You probably can save a lot of time.

The way I see it, the great disadvantage on using this is you are creating a webpage instead of a mobile app. You cant use native components and your app gets less responsive. As you are already on webviews, I believe you can only find benefits on these platforms.