# UIWebview javascript bridge

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview

I am supposed to communicate between Objective C and javascript code, i also want to return objects from objective c to js and js back to objective c. For that I used a library called Webviewjavascriptbridge. But i could not get a return value from objective c to js. Can some one tell me if there is any other library that can achieve this? I tried with the libraries referred in this link [iOS JavaScript bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473582/ios-javascript-bridge) but i could not get a return value from objective c to js.

Comment: In iOS7, JavascriptCore.Framework is supported. Recommend this library, you can communicate between javascript and objc easily with UIWebView. https://github.com/liaojinxing/HybridBridge

Answer (score 3):

`JSBridge` is an easy to use library to communicate between `JS` and `cocoa`/`Objective`-c`.

http://code.google.com/p/jsbridge-to-cocoa/

If you want to send a message to Javascript from app then `UIWebView` has a method for you. This is a code I implemented to assign filled data in webview to a Customer.

```
NSString *jsSave=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"set_customer(%@);",self.customer.customerId];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsSave];
```

set_customer is the method of JS.

Comment: Hi Abid Thanks for your answer, is it possible to return objects from objective c to js by using this library.

Comment: Yes you can. if you visit above mentioned link then you'll see step-by-step instruction of how to use this library. They also have a sample xCode project for help.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out, might be what you need:

http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/

Comment: Hi ismael, thanks for your answer. i have checked the link but that doesnt provide any way to pass objects from js to obj c.if i am wrong,please let me know how to achieve it.

Comment: Well you can't pass an object directly, you need to make a json and work with that

Comment: Absolutely awesome and simple idea, the one in the link, I must say. Copying here the most important fact: `The only thing we have to change is in Javascript code. Instead of changing the document location, we create an IFrame and set its location to a value that trigger the shouldStartLoadWithRequest method.`

Answer (score 0):

You want a return value from `ObjC` to `js`. Maybe that means your `js` code needs a parameter provided by `ObjC` code. Then you can try this:

```
NSString *returnValue = [self someMethod];
NSString *jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"yourJsMethodName:('%@')", returnValue];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];
```

Is that what you want? I hope it helps.