# How to call JavaScript from native code

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS JavaScript bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473582/ios-javascript-bridge)

i am having one webview and one UIButton .
i want to make javascript call from native code .
How can i be able to do that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *param =@"Mango";       
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"JSMethod('%@')", param]];
```

Comment: from ibaction i need to call this function or webview delegate

Comment: If you wanna call the JS method on click of the button,you need to put this logic in the IBAction. If you wanna call the JS method while loading page into UIWebView,put this logic in delegate method webViewDidStartLoad ..

Comment: can you send me some sample code for that

Comment: Once check this link http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/

Comment: thanks it worked i was doing some mistake ....

Answer (score 1):

Follow these links.
[Using an html button to call a javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947263/using-an-html-button-to-call-a-javascript-function)

http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/02/09/javascript-5-ways-to-call-a-function.aspx

http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3749371.htm?highlight=msg3753441

These may help

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to solve your query:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myJSFunction()"];
```

Comment: from IBAction i need to call this function or webview delegate

Comment: Anywhere you need to call that function.