# Call Objective C method when DOM changes.

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I need to call objective C code when ever the DOM changes (highlighting happens using JavaScript) from JavaScript code. Is this possible?

I cannot use the delegate

> shouldStartLoadWithRequest:

as it is never called when the DOM is changed. And I do not want to do a hard refresh either.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to introduce a communication bridge between iOS and javascript. Check this out [iOS JavaScript bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473582/ios-javascript-bridge)

Comment: excellent. thanks for pointing me in the right direction. How do I make my objective c code bind to a custom JavaScript event? A few lines of code will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: You just have to bind the event to a handler inside your javascript. whenever your handler gets called in javascript, you can change the value(url) of window.location which tries to redirect the current page in the webview which is caught by the shouldStartLoadWithRequest delegate. You can use the url to pass data from js to obj c.