# Compose SMS with jquery for iphone app

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, sms

Does anyone have a stable and tested way to create compose sms functionality using jquerymobile for ios

I have speny months working on this following plugin posts that are supposed to work to then find a raft of posts and fixes needed and still they do not work

For the record the many posts that recommend using a hyper link to open the compose sms screen DOES NOT WORK on IOS 7

my app sends data to a web service which then builds the body of the SMS message based on paramaters sent to it from the web service and returns the value back to the page which i then need to attach to the compose sms button. When the user presses the button the compose sms screen opens and passes the values sent from the web service.

no matter what i try from the numerous plugins i have downloaded clicking the button does not open the composes sms screen

In frustration i have had an indian programmer create the functionality but it uses object-c and as the remainder of the site is written in jquery i do not know how to pass the jquery variable sent from the web service to the object c button

Assistance is appreciated as i am so so tired having worked on this for months without success and non of the solutions i come across online work

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try js-bridge call native `MFMessageComposeViewController` in javascript

[iOS JavaScript bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473582/ios-javascript-bridge)

Comment: thanks but i am a totally newbie to ios development and have no understanding of object C what i am ideally lookig for are examples that actually send jquery paramaters to a objectc button that have been tested and work, i do not have the detailed knowledge of either jquery mobile or object c syntax to "try and see if it works" as if it does not i would not know how to tweek it to make it work