# how do i call objective c code from javascript

Tags: ios, objective-c

i've some `javascript code` on the webpage in the `uiwebview` that i want to use to call one of my objective c methods.

i found some code online which i decided to use. but it still doesn't seem to be working. can anyone see where the problem is?

**javascript code:**

```
function someMethod() {
window.location = "ios:webToNativeCall";
}
```

**objective c code:**

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"ios:"]) {

        // Call the given selector
        [self performSelector:@selector(webToNativeCall)];
        // Cancel the location change
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

-(void)webToNativeCall
{
    //my code here
}
```

i'm not sure, how to use this method so it might be that i have implemented it incorrectly.

does anyone have any ideas about what could be causing this?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You might want to check the [old inquiry][1]
That can maybe help.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662473/how-to-call-objective-c-from-javascript

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473582/ios-javascript-bridge

Answer (score 1):

1. This code looks ok, please check whether delegate for UIWebView is set or not.
2. Otherwise you can use **[EasyJSWebView](https://github.com/dukeland/EasyJSWebView)** download it from Github, it is easy to use.

Comment: I have edited your answer to actually include the link to the Github repository for EasyJSWebView.

Answer (score 0):

You must have missed to link the delegate.

Either connect the delegate of the webView to the file owner in the .xib file

or

Use Following code

```
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
webView.delegate = self;
```

in your `viewDidLoad` also write below code

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"yourJavascriptFunction()"];
```

Hope it helps you...

Comment: How does this answer the question? Have you read the question? -1