# How to detect a play button touch for youtube video inside UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube

In my app I have a UIWebView with embedded youtube video in it.

Does anyone know how I can detect the tap on the play button there?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use JS Bridge to pass the event from Javascript.

To know more about JS Bridge, see [iOS JavaScript bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473582/ios-javascript-bridge).

Comment: How can be bridge js with objc when loading an youtube page?