# How to pass a variable from javascript to objective C and Objective C to Javasctipt in ios

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

I am a iOS Developer, am new to javascript.

I wants to create a communication between Javascript to Objective C and Objective C to Javascript.

How to pass a variable from javascript to objective C and Objective C to Javasctipt in ios.

If any one have references please let us know about this?

Answer (score 0):

I program JavaScript when using Parse CloudCode.  In my case, I use CloudCode to call the Stripe API.

For example:

**Objective-C**

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                                 @"customerId": stripeCustomerId,
                                 @"amount": @(100),      
                            };

[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"chargeCustomer" withParameters:parameters block:block];
```

**JavaScript**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("chargeCustomer", function(request, response) {
  Stripe.Charges.create({
      amount: request.params.amount, // in cents
      currency: "usd",
      customer: request.params.customerId,
    },{
    success: function (httpResponse) {
        console.log(httpResponse);
        response.success(httpResponse);
    },
    error: function (httpResponse) {
        console.error(httpResponse.message);
        response.error(httpResponse.message);
    }
  });
});
```

As you can see, to pass on the variable from objective-c to javascript in this case, you use request.params.

Comment: This answer is very specific to Parse, while the OP asked for a general approach to communicate between native and JS code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native iOS objects to do this.

**From Obj-C to JS**

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```

It injects or calls pre-existing method/object in the page loaded in the UIWebview. It returns the value that JS return to you

[UIWebView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:)

**From JS to Obj-C**

Implementing `UIWebView` protocol you can handle the request before it will start:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest (NSURLRequest *)request navigationType (UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

So, from JS you have to call a URL with a custom schema http such as `test://`. Then you will parse the request in the delegate method I wrote before.

Comment: If u have any idea about JS to Obj-C, can u explain with an example.., Actually I have tried.. but not achieve.. am unable to get the objects from js to ObjC

Comment: From JS call `window.location = "test://functionName?queryString";` and in the method listed before, check for the schema:
`if ([request URL] scheme] isEqualToString: @"test"]{ // doSomething }`

Comment: May this will help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473582/ios-javascript-bridge

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting iOS8, you could consider to use `WKWebView` rather than `UIWebView`, which has considerably improved in this regard. Good starting points are the [the `WKWebView` reference docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/index.html) and this [NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/wkwebkit/).

Comment: Target is iOS 7, not using swift.., basic communication Pass a string to Objective C, How am able to receive that string.. how can i call Objc methods in Javascirpt

Comment: If your target is <iOS8, then the best you can do is what LucaD has described. You can't directly call Obj-C methods from JS, you can just work-around by intercepting location changes via the `
webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` delegate method.