# WKWebView Javascript Bridge solution for Android?

Tags: android, ios, webview, wkwebview

I am currently figuring out how to implement a JS bridge to communicate from webview -> app.

Especially for iOS with the new WKWebView there is a new cool solution using the webkit messagehandlers (good blog post: http://www.kinderas.com/technology/2014/6/15/wkwebview-and-javascript-in-ios-8-using-swift).

Question: In my understanding this is an iOS only solution, right? Usually we have Android & iOS apps which are using the same webpage, which means that a general solution is needed.

There is one alterate "old" solution which is described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9473941/5156317

Is this really the only possibility which works with Android & iOS? Or is there any support for MessageHandlers for Android?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, have you find a solution? I'm also looking for a cross platform JS to native bridging using both Android and iOS with a `WKWebView`

Comment: Hi @Jan, I added the answer/solution that we are going to work with now. It does not rely on the same javascript on the webpage, but is the official solution.