# How can I call an Objective-C method from Javascript which is loaded in web page(UIWebView)?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have an IOS application which has a web browser in it.

When this web browser is displayed, it navigates to a page on Internet, say http://something.com:8080/success.php

Is it possible to place a javascript code on this web site, which communicates with the native application? Can it call an Objective-C method?

I tried this, but didn't work.

On Javascript side:

Your javascript code will navigate to a 'fake' URL that you will filter on the method above. Something like:

```
window.location = "js2objc://save:param";
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473582/ios-javascript-bridge

Comment: As a mentioned, this window.location should call shouldStartLoadWithRequest in objective c but it is not working.

Comment: Is your webView delegate pointing at the class where shouldStartLoadWithRequest is defined?